# Create a while loop to concat columns from weekly excel files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, append, concatenation

I have 3 years of excel weekly files with the format "trucks from 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-07.xlsx", "trucks from 2018-01-08 to 2018-01-14.xlsx" and so on. I need to extract 4 cells with totals from each file and build a dataframe with the weekly values adding columns to the right with the values.

I've tried a while loop cleaning each excel within the loop but somehow I'm having a beginners problem to append a new column to the right of the dataframe.

The expected result would be a Dataframe with this data:
Columns: Week 1, Week 2... Week N (or the start date)
Rows: Dock 1, Dock2, Dock 3, Dock 4

[edit]
The results I'm getting is Index is correct with Dock 1, Dock 2, Dock 3, Dock 4.
After that 2 columns with the values from last file in both columns.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

start_date = date(2018, 1, 1)
end_date1 = date(2018, 1, 7)
end_date = date(2018, 1, 14)
delta = timedelta(days=7)

while start_date <= end_date:
    tr = pd.read_excel('trucks from {} to {}.xlsx'.format(start_date, end_date1))

    # I clean up the columns
    tr = tr.drop('Unnamed: 0', 1)
    tr = tr.drop('Unnamed: 1', 1)
    tr = tr.drop('Unnamed: 2', 1)

    # I clean up the rows
    tr = tr.drop(tr.loc[:, 'Unnamed: 4':'Unnamed: 29'].head(0).columns, axis=1)
    tr = tr.loc[[34, 51, 58, 66], :]

    # I rename the rows of interest
    tr = tr.rename(index={34: 'Dock 1', 51: 'Dock 2', 58: 'Dock 3', 66: 'Dock 4'})

    # Closing the loop and adding a new column at the end
    tr[start_date] = tr
    tr.append(tr)
    start_date += delta
    end_date1 += delta
```

Comment: What is the result you get for now ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, first time I post, I added an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me 1 month to crack this so I will share the solution to this problem. I had to create a new dataframe and concatenate itself to tr, like this:

```
# Transpose in order to have the data in columns
tr = tr.transpose()

# I created a new dataframe to store the data
result = pd.concat([result, tr], sort=False)

# I close the loop adding 7 days in order to store weekly data
start_date += delta
end_date1 += delta
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the problem is that you reassign `tr` every steps. Under the while instruction you first assign `tr` as follows:

```
tr = pd.read_excel('trucks from {} to {}.xlsx'.format(start_date, end_date1))
```

So `tr` is a DataFrame which is good because this is what you want, you want a DataFrame to perform some operations on it.

But at the end of your loop you do this:

```
# Closing the loop and adding a new column at the end
    tr[start_date] = tr
    tr.append(tr)
    start_date += delta
    end_date1 += delta
```

Your first line assigns to the column `start_date` your current DataFrame which I think is weird and I'm not sure this is what you want to do.
Then you [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to your DataFrame your own DataFrame. At the next step of your loop, you will lose what you had because you reassign `tr`.

Try to create a DataFrame holding every DataFrame that you will fetch ( every `tr` you construct). You can use the [apppend](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) function as you already did or the [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) function.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, there's something wrong on this last 2 lines, still can't figure out a workaround.

Comment: The wrong thing is that you shouldn't append to `tr` every step of your loop but have for example a `df` DataFrame to which you append the content of `tr` every step of your loop after you've done the processing.
Otherwise because you reassign at every step of your loop the `tr` content you lose the content of the previous steps.